# How to migrate all sites from one HubSite from one tenant to another

Tags: migration, pnp-provision

I have got at my test tenant a lot of sites conected by hubsite. It is posibility to copy only the sites from one Tenant to another Tenant ?Production Tenant. Have you try to do this task in your enviroment ?

Comment: You are simply asking for Migration of all site collections from one tenant to another tenant & for this I recommend 3rd party tools like ShareGate, Metavis, Proventeq, Quest or Metalogix.

Comment: I write a script from powershell